# Alternatives to CTEs in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-design, subquery, ms-access-2010

I work with MS Access 2010 on a daily basis and I want to know if there are alternatives to a **Common Table Expression** as it is used in SQL Server, and how it affects performance?

For example, is it better to create a subquery or is it better to call a query from another query, which essentially is very similar..

Example:

```
SELECT A.field1,A.Date
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE B WHERE B.Date = Restriction )
```

or

```
SELECT A.field1,A.Date
FROM SavedQueryB
```

SavedQueryB:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE B WHERE B.Date = Restriction
```

I feel having multiple queries makes it easier to debug and manage, but does it affect performance when the data-set is very large?

Also, I've seen some videos about implementing the queries thru VBA, however I'm not very comfortable doing it that way yet.

Essentially. **What is more efficient or a better practice? Any suggestion or recommendations on better practices?**
I am mostly self taught, through videos, and books, and some programming background (VB.NET)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really context-dependent as a host of scenarios will decide the most efficient outcome including data types, join tables, indexes, and more. In essence and for simple queries like posted `SELECT` statmeents, the two queries are equivalent but the Jet/ACE's (underlying engine of MS Access) query optimizer may decide a different plan again according to structural needs of the query. Possibly, calling an external query adds a step in execution plan but then subqueries can be executed as self-contained tables then linked to main tables.

Recall SQL's general Order of Operations which differs from typed order as each step involves a virtual table (see [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)):

```
FROM clause       --VT1
ON clause         --VT2
WHERE clause      --VT3
GROUP BY clause   --VT4
HAVING clause     --VT5
SELECT clause     --VT6
ORDER BY clause   --VT7
```

What can be said is for stored query objects, MS Access analyzes and caches the optimized "best plan" version. This is often the argument to use stored queries over VBA string queries which the latter was not optimized before execution. Even further, Access' *query* object is similar to other RDMS' *view* object (though Jet/ACE does have the `VIEW` and `PROCEDURE` objects). A regular discussion in the SQL world involves your very question of efficiency and best practices: [views vs subqueries](https://www.google.com/#q=views+vs+subqueries) and usually the answer returns "it depends". So, experiment on a needs basis.

And here CTEs are considered "inline-views" denoted by `WITH` clause (not yet supported in JET/ACE). SQL programmers may use CTEs for readibility and maintainability as you avoid referencing same statement multiple times in body of statement. All in all, use what fits your coding rituals and project requirements, then adjust as needed.

Resources

- [MS Access 2007 Query Performance
  Tips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824%28v=office.12%29.aspx#odc_ac2007_ta_PerformanceTipsToSpeedUpYourAccessDB_QueryPerformanceTips) *- with note on subquery performance*
- [Intermediate Microsoft Jet
  SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28v=office.10%29.aspx#acintsql_subq)
  *- with note on subqueries* (just learned about the `ANY/SOME/ALL`)
- [Microsoft Jet 3.5 Performance White 
  Paper](http://documents.mx/documents/microsoft-jet-35-performance.html)
  *- with note on query plans*

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the information I was looking for and it has been difficult to find it with the simplicity of your explanation! Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

For the simplest queries, such as those in your question, I doubt you would see a significant performance difference between a subquery and a "stacked query" (one which uses another saved query as its data source) approach.  And perhaps the db engine would even use the same query plan for both.  (If you're interested, you can use [SHOWPLAN](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms%20access%20showplan) to examine the query plans.)

The primary performance driver for those 2 examples will be whether the db engine can use indexed retrieval to fetch the rows which satisfy the `WHERE` restriction.  If `TABLE.Date` is not indexed, the query will require a full table scan.  That would suck badly with a very large dataset, and the performance impact from a full scan should far overshadow any difference between a subquery and stacked query.

The situation could be different with a complex subquery as [Allen Browne explains](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html#Performance):

> Complex subqueries on tables with many records can be slow to run.

Among the potential fixes for subquery performance problems, he suggests ...

> Use stacked queries instead of subqueries. Create a separate saved
>   query for JET to execute first, and use it as an input "table" for
>   your main query. This pre-processing is usually (but not always)
>   faster than a subquery. Likewise, try performing aggregation in one
>   query, and then create another query that operates on the aggregated
>   results. This post-processing can be orders of magnitude faster than a
>   query that tries to do everything in a single query with subqueries.

I think your best answer will come from testing more complex real world examples.  The queries in your question are so simple that conclusions drawn from them will likely not apply to those real world queries.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recall where but there are discussion out there about this topic of nested or sub-queries.  Basically they all suggest saved queries and then referenced the saved query.

From a personal experience, nested queries are extremely difficult to troubleshoot or modify later. Also, if they get too deep I have experienced a performance hit.

Allen Browne has several tips and tricks listed out [here](http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html)

The one place I use nest queries a lot are in the criteria of action queries.  This way I do not have any joins and can limit some of the "cannot perform this operation" issue.

Finally, using query strings in VBA.  I have found it be much easier to build parameter queries and then in VBA set a variable to the QueryDef and add in the parameters rather than build up a query string in VBA. So much easier to troubleshoot and modify later.

Just my two cents.